# jQueryUI - dragging element in table issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am using jqueryui to create a custom scheduler, but there is an issue with drag/drop events. If I have a drag element which is 2 cells long, it will not trigger the drop event, however if it is odd number, like 3, it WILL trigger it. That is because he chooses the middle droppable element as target, but if it has 2 elements he has no middle element... Does anyone know a workaround, or some other events I can use? Here is an image of what I was trying to achieve:

[image]

code for draggable/droppable:

```
 $(".draggable").draggable({
        containment: '.calendar-cells',
        grid: [47, 27]
    });

    $(".day").droppable({
        drop: function (event, ui) {
            console.log(event);
        }
    });
```

EDIT: Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/k5ovt5gk/3/

Comment: I think you need to publish a code that reproduces the issue to get help with debugging in this web site.

Comment: Thanks, I just added fiddle

Answer (score 1):

Solved it with css in the end... gave every odd cell .1px more width so it could find a middle element... Dumb solution but works for now